# Как определить, работает ли mongoose с бд на данный момент

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Есть js скрипт, в котором идет соединение с mongodb, после чего совершается множество апдейтов всевозможных в базу, и еще некоторые асинхронные операции. Скрипт запускается по крону. Проблема в том, что процесы будут скапливаться в памяти, потому как я не знаю, в какой момент оборвать соединение с базой. Пытался обернуть в промис:

```
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://' + config.DB_HOST + '/' + config.DB_NAME );

var promise = new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
    // много запросов асинхронных сложных
    resolve();
});

promise.then( function() {
    mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Разрыв соединения происходит быстрее, чем совершаются апдейты, и вся бизнес-логика крешится. Была идея с setTimeout'ом, но это костыль ужасный. Что еще остается, отловить идентификаторы запросов в db.currentOp().inprog, запоминать их и ждать, когда все завершатся? Совсем сложно как-то. Как же мне дождаться завершения выполнения работы монгуса, всех его запросов? Может у него есть свойство какое-то? Не могу найти информацию нигде.

***UPDATE***

Попытался через stream - тоже безрезультатно:

```
var stream = userModel.find( условия ).stream();

stream.on('data', function ( data ) {

    // много запросов асинхронных сложных

}).on('close', function () {
    console.log( 'connection closed..' );
    mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Однако, "просачивается" больше апдейтов, чем в первом случае. Но соединение все-таки закрывается, не дожидаясь завершения остальных апдейтов.

Answer (score 1):

Событие на открытие соединения с БД не работает?

`mongoose.connection.on('open', () => {});`